# How can I load a custom font with CSS in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I am creating a simple web page and I am applying a custom font (Roboto). I have declared them in the CSS file but Chrome detects it fine and Safari does not.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto500.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/roboto500.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto500.woff2') format('woff2'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto500.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto500.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto500.svg') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto700.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/roboto700.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto700.woff2') format('woff2'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto700.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto700.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('/fonts/roboto700.svg') format('svg');
}

h1.site-title,
h2.subtitles {
    font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4.subtitles {
    font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}
```

I checked with the Safari console to see if it was getting the fonts, and it does, but when I look at the files one by one, they don't match the original font.

Comment: Just checking: You've done a hard refresh/cache clear?

Comment: It is just a suggestion but have you already checked out the roboto font in google fonts? https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

Comment: @MeltingDog I did a history and cookie deletion from Safari, but I don't know if there is a more thorough option for this and I stayed on the surface.

Comment: @EmielVdV I was reading that apparently on Mac, the fonts with ttf extension gave problems, so I found this page: http://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/roboto?subsets=latin and I downloaded the 500 and 700 (Latin). But I don't know if it's a font problem. 

The website you gave me only allows to download them in this ttf format that was supposed to give problems...

Comment: @Ludiras so it does not work if you just put a link from google fonts in your css?

Comment: @EmielVdV I finally managed to do it in a similar way to what you had proposed :)

Comment: @Ludiras Great I wish you the best in your development journey

Comment: See this article: [Safari doesn't render self-hosted Google Fonts](https://dev.to/masakudamatsu/don-t-locally-host-google-fonts-for-the-sake-of-safari-bkg#the-root-cause-fingerprinting). I don't know how self-hosted fonts would allow for browser fingerprinting, but it seems the issue started when Apple introduced these protections.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, thanks to some comments and such, I got it to work using another download link:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto

From here Google offers different components to add to the CSS of your project, what I did was, just in case in the future that typography was no longer available in that link and I lost it, I downloaded it from the link that appears and I put it locally in my project and linked it with the relative path.

I have no idea if it was because the files I downloaded didn't work or any other reason, but the fact is that from this link and using only the one in woff2 format, it works both in Chrome and Safari.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url(../fonts/roboto/roboto.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

I hope this may be of help to someone in the future. Many thanks to all of you who have responded.